# Finding the path to a Perl module upon loading

Tags: perl, module, path, environment

I am using a legacy Perl application which loads a library, call it "blah". I need to know where does "blah" resides in my file system.

I am not familiar at all with Perl, and I wonder what is the equivalent way to print the path to the module, along the lines of the special variable `__file__` in Python. In other words, the Perl equivalent of the following Python script:

```
import blah
print blah.__file__
```

Many thanks.

Comment: After the postings I have made, I wonder, how is the file being loaded? `use` or `require`?

Comment: It is being loaded as ``use``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [found the following one-liner](http://www.symkat.com/174/find-perl-module-path/) which solved my problem:

```
$ perl -MList::Util -e'print $_ . " => " . $INC{$_} . "\n" for keys %INC'
```

Where `-MList::Util` stands for the `List::Util` module (in my case, I used `-MBlah`)

Answer (score 7):

```
use blah;
print $INC{'blah.pm'};

use Blah1::Blah2::blah;
print $INC{'Blah1/Blah2/blah.pm'};
```

---

The case is significant, even on Windows. `use Blah` will create an entry for `$INC{'Blah.pm'}` and `use blah` will create an entry for `$INC{'blah.pm'}`.

```
C:\>perl -MList::util -e "print join $/, keys %INC"
XSLoader.pm
Carp.pm
warnings/register.pm
Exporter.pm
vars.pm
strict.pm
List/util.pm
warnings.pm
```

Comment: It unfortunately did not work for me; the thing did not print anything, and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: if you are in windows and the module name is like the second case `::` nested, you might have to use '\' rather than '/'. Read perldoc perlvar for `%INC` for more (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Comment: @Joel - Windows versions of Perl use '/' in `%INC` since at least 5.6.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment on mob's answer, try a more loose use of `%INC` to help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use blah;

foreach (keys %INC) {
  if (m'blah.pm') {
    print "$_ => $INC{$_}\n"; 
  }
}
```

The relevant [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) on the subject says

> %INC
>
> The hash %INC contains entries
>   for each filename included via the do,
>   require, or use operators. The key is
>   the filename you specified (with
>   module names converted to pathnames),
>   and the value is the location of the
>   file found. The require operator uses
>   this hash to determine whether a
>   particular file has already been
>   included.
>
> If the file was loaded via a
>   hook (e.g. a subroutine reference, see
>   require for a description of these
>   hooks), this hook is by default
>   inserted into %INC in place of a
>   filename. Note, however, that the hook
>   may have set the %INC entry by itself
>   to provide some more specific info.

If even that doesn't help, you may, as the previous document suggests, read about the [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) command, to help you understand how it is getting to be loaded in the first place. This should help you back it out, perhaps by iterating through `@INC`, which are the folders that Perl will search for to find files to be `require`d.